# Not sure how to calculate the exepected value of five coins?

Tags: random-variables, expected-value

The question gives an RV of X

$$X = \begin{cases} 
\phantom{-}1 & \text{if}\; \ 0.5 \\
-1 & \text{if}\; 0.5 \end{cases} $$

We flip a fair coin where 1 represents heads with a probability of 0.5 while -1 represents tails.

I know that flipping one coin will give me the expected value of 0 because 1*0.5 + - -1 * 0.5 = 0.

However, I do I get the expected value of flipping 5 fair coins?

Comment: Just use your result and the fact that expected value of a sum is sum of expected values.

Comment: Sorry could you explain more specifically? I am not sure what the "sum" means?

Comment: Well you could for each $k=1,2,3,4,5$ define the random variable $X_k$ to denote the result of the $k$th coin flip, using your definition of $X$ for each. Then use $E(X_1+\cdots+X_5)=E(X_1)+ \cdots + E(X_5).$

Comment: So does this mean we just add five zeros together? Because that is the sum of the expected values for five coins? Thus, the expected value would be zero for five coins in this case?

Comment: Yes. Note that if you used 1 for heads and 0 for tails, and did the same calculation, you would get expected value 2.5 for the 5 tosses. That is same as (1/2)*5 for total number of heads. By using 1 for heads and -1 for tails you end up finding (expected no. heads) minus (expected no. tails) which is naturally zero since for a fair coin one expects same number of each on average.